# "Error 1004: Unable to set the Hidden Property of the Range class" - on rows that are auto-hidden when their value is ""

Tags: excel, vba, row, hide

I have a worksheet that I am creating for my company.  I have set several rows different ranges to automatically hide if that range has a value of "".  The issue is that, now, I have protected the sheet and my auto-hiding function is not working because the rows are protected against formatting.  I know that I can un-protect the sheet and then re-protect it and allow the users to format the rows for a  quick fix but I don't want the user to have even that tiny bit of ability.  I am specifically getting the run-time error on either `xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = True` or `xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = False` depending on which solution I try.  Here is the VBA code for the auto-hiding function in the work sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRg As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each xRg In Range("C24,C52,C81,C90:C123,A124:A126,A130:A353")
            If xRg.Value = "" Then
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next xRg
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've tried a few things to fix the problem that I found on Google but none-have worked so far.  I can't locate examples of everything I have tried but here is what I have currently:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Sheets("yoursheetname").Unprotect Password:="abc"
    Dim xRg As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each xRg In Range("C24,C52,C81,C90:C123,A124:A126,A130:A353")
            If xRg.Value = "" Then
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next xRg
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sheets("yoursheetname").Protect Password:="abc", AllowFormattingRows:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: The Worksheet Change event triggers when a cell is manually changed. This code wouldn't make sense if those cells were the ones in the range. So we can conclude that the cells in the range contain formulas. You should restrict when the code should run to only the cells that can change the result of the formulas e.g. if the formula in `C24` is `=Sum(C2:C23)` then you would use `If Not Intersect(Range("C2:C23"), Target) Is Nothing Then: If C24.Value = "" Then...`. Otherwise, this code may severely slow down the workbook since it runs every time you enter a value even into irrelevant cells.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out everyone.  The problem is that I was referencing the sheet number instead of the sheet name.  Here is the solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRg As Range
    Sheets("CFIA Label Verifier").Unprotect Password:="67341289"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each xRg In Range("C24,C52,C81,C90:C123,A124:A126,A130:A353")
            If xRg.Value = "" Then
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next xRg
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sheets("CFIA Label Verifier").Protect Password:="67341289", AllowFormattingCells:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Shortcut: `xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = xRg.Value = ""`